# CAShapeLayer not receiving touches

Tags: swift, uiview, calayer, cashapelayer, cgpath

I made a CAShapeLayer inside of a UIView like so:

```
    let shapeMask: CAShapeLayer = {
        let sl = CAShapeLayer()
        sl.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 133, height: 133)
        sl.lineWidth = 2
        sl.strokeColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
        sl.fillColor = UIColor.purple.cgColor
        let shapeLayerPath = UIBezierPath()
        shapeLayerPath.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), radius: 68, startAngle: -.pi/2, endAngle: -.pi/4, clockwise: true)
        shapeLayerPath.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), radius: 180, startAngle: -.pi/4, endAngle: -.pi/2, clockwise: false)
        shapeLayerPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: -68))
        shapeLayerPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: -180))
        shapeLayerPath.close()
        sl.path = shapeLayerPath.cgPath            
        return sl
    }()
```

I added it to the view in the UIView's init like so:

```
    layer.addSublayer(shapeMask)
    shapeMask.frame = CGRect(x: 181, y: 180, width: 133, height: 133)
```

Which looks like this:

[image: Shape Layer]

And I'm using `touchesBegan` to see if the user touches inside of the ShapeLayer

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {        
    let touchOne = touches.first
    let point = touchOne!.location(in: self)

    if (shapeMaskOne.path?.contains(point))! {
        print("shapeMaskTouched")
    }
}
```

But when I touch inside the ShapeLayer, nothing is printed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Leo my bad. Its updated now.

Comment: don't  change the shape bounds and start with a regular shape

Comment: @Leo changing the shape bounds didn't do anything, it just moved the shape